# Committed to the correct branch, but then pushed the wrong branch, how to undo the push?

Tags: git, github

I made some changes on `branch1`, committed them, checked out `branch2`, made changes and committed them.

I pushed `branch1` to GitHub by mistake.

I then pushed `branch2`.

Because I only meant to push `branch2`, I want to undo the `branch1` push.

Basically I did the following:

```
git checkout -b branch1
//make some changes on branch1
git commit -am "changes on branch1"
git checkout -b branch2
//make some different changes on branch2
git commit -am "changes on branch2"
git push origin branch1 //whoops!
git push origin branch2 //this is what I meant to do
```

I want to undo the `branch1` push but not the `branch2` push; how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only pushed a single change

```
git push origin +branch1^:branch1
```

will roll back the branch1 head on origin to the previous commit.